# Vue Props not working for child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have root element that has logged in user data and on user profile component I am passing logged in user data as props.

But when I try to call User object properties in child component it throws error as undefined. I don't see any value in child component.

app.js

```
Vue.component("usersmanagment", require("./components/usersmanagment"));

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        'v-select': vSelect
    },
    data() {
        return {
            AuthorizedUser: {
                Email : "",
                FirstName : "",
                LastName : "",
                CreatedUtcDateTime : "",
                IsActive : ""
            }           
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        let vm = this;      
        vm.getAuthorisedUserProfile();
    },
    methods: {
        getAuthorisedUserProfile() {
            let vm = this;          
            // just return auth user data
    }

});
```

Than on child component I am passing props

```
module.exports = {
    props : ["AuthorizedUser"],

};
```

and in my view file I am Asp.Net MVC

```
<usersmanagment inline-template>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="AuthorizedUser.FirstName">
</usersmanagment>
```

I can see in vue chrome dev tools that Authorized user get updated but its value don't get updated on child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what solved my problem. I have to bind props with child template.

```
<profile inline-template v-bind:authorized-user="authorizedUser">
        <div>

            <input type="text" v-model="authorizedUser.FirstName" class="form-control">
        </div>    

    </profile>
```

Answer (score 16):

You haven't included it here, but my guess would be that you are passing the prop using `camelCase` but you need to pass it using `kebab-case` (see: [camelCase vs kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case)). So make sure you are doing:

```
<child-component :authorized-user="AuthorizedUser"></child-component>
```

Comment: I am assigning it to input element like this v-model="AuthorizedUser.FirstName".  Can I use v-bind with input element ?

Comment: Inside your child component? That would be a direct mutation of a prop and should throw an error. How are you passing the `AuthorizedUser` value to the child component?

Comment: module.exports = {
    props : ["AuthorizedUser"],

};

Comment: That's declaring the prop, you still need to pass it through to the component. Here's a JSFiddle to show you what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/qteo58jL/

Comment: But I am getting undefined in created function.

Comment: Is `usersmanagement` the child component that should be receiving the `prop`? From what I can see you are using a `slot` which remains in the context of the parent, you aren't passing a prop at all, you have just declared one, so the child component has no idea about the authorized user. see: [Compilation Scope](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope)

Comment: OK I see your point but just for clarification whats the correct way to pass data to child component.

Comment: Through a prop, just like I did in my JSFiddle above, you cannot pass data through slots because they are compiled in the parent scope, in your case I don't think you want to use a slot at all, just pass the value through as a prop and emit it back to the parent: see: [Composing Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)

Comment: OK I got what I was missing I needed to declare it in view with v-bind. Such a silly mistake. Thanks for taking your time to create jsfiddle. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that something like this can also be caused by a missing :key prop in a v-for.